# cant figure out how to create a get set statement

Tags: c#, forms, combobox

I try to make a `get` `set` statement but it doesn't work. I have no idea why.
Basically I have a form named `form1` that contains a combo-box with names and a button.

The button opens a new form `form2` that has a text box. I want to be able to add the text in the text box to the combo box in `form1`. I searched the web a bit and found that in order to do so i need to create `get` and `set` statement instead of playing with the privacy of the controls.

The `set` and `get` statement doesn't work. It says only assignment call increment decrement and new object can be used as statement.

Much appreciate your help.

```
public string GuideNameFunc(){
    Get { return GuideName.Text; }
    set { GuideName.Text = value; }
}
```

Comment: Looks like c#. You should add the tag of your programming language so more specialized people will see your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove it `()` from your code.

```
public string GuideNameFunc{
    get { return GuideName.Text; }
    set { GuideName.Text = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public string GuideNameField{
    get { return GuideName.Text; }
    set { GuideName.Text = value; }
}
```